# UWP Webview Not Firing NavigationCompleted From Local Server

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, uwp, httplistener

I have a WPF server tray application that provides local html content to a WebView of a UWP app.  In order to time a Storyboard animation properly, I need to try and take advantage of the WebView.NavigationCompleted event, but it is not firing when loading content from my server app.

After some troubleshooting I have narrowed it down to my server being the problem. It's not the html content itself because if I load the same page using NavigateToString then the event will fire fine.  And if do regular Navigate to a URI from the Internet (e.g. https://google.com) the event fires then as well.  It's only when getting html from my server that it doesn't fire (unless I quit the server, then it fires like 10 sec later). I don't know enough about HTTP to know what the WebView isn't receiving that would trigger the event.

**Client code (UWP):**

```
private UIElement MyUIElement;
private int AnimationDuration;
private WebView MyWebView;

public async void ChangeBackground(UIElement uIElement, int animationDuration)
{
    MyUIElement = uIElement;
    MyWebView = MyUIElement.GetChildOfType<WebView>();
    MyWebView.NavigationCompleted += WebView_NavigationCompleted;
    MyWebView.DOMContentLoaded += WebView_DOMContentLoaded;
    AnimationDuration = animationDuration;
    var hideAnimation = MyUIElement.Fade(0, AnimationDuration);
    hideAnimation.Completed += HideAnimation_Completed;
    await hideAnimation.StartAsync();
}
private void HideAnimation_Completed(object sender, AnimationSetCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MyWebView.Navigate(myUriFromMyLocalServer);
}

private void WebView_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{
    // this fires
}

private void WebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
   // this doesn't fire
}
```

**Server code (WPF):**

```
private void ResponseHtmlContent(HttpListenerContext context, string htmlFileStr)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(htmlFileStr);
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    context.Response.KeepAlive = false;
    context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    context.Response.Close();
}
```

I've tried different variations of Flush, Close, and Dispose, none of them seem to do the trick.

Comment: WebView.LoadCompleted event same problem.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I did not, I just used DOMContentLoaded.